# C++: Incorporating inheritance, polymorphism, and factories

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, factory

I'm currently trying to make a pair of classes which depend on each other.  Essentially, objects of class `B` create objects of class `A`.  However, I am also using an inheritance hierarchy, so all derivatives of class `B` must also be able to create derivatives of class `A` (each derivative of `B` corresponds to a derivative of `A`, so `DerB1` makes `DerA1` objects, and `DerB2` makes `DerA2` objects).

I'm having problems with my implementation, and it may be silly, but I would like to see if anyone knows what to do.  My code is below (I HATE reading other people's code, so I tried to make it as easy to read as possible...only a few important bits, which I commented to explain)

```
class BaseB {} // Declare BaseB early to use in BaseA constructor

class BaseA
{
public:
BaseA(BaseB* b) {}; // Declare the BaseA constructor (callable by all B classes, which pass a pointer to themselves to the constructor so the A objects can keep track of their parent)
}

class DerA:public BaseA
{
    DerA(BaseB* b):BaseA(b) {}; // Inherit the BaseA constructor, and use initialization list
}

class BaseB
{
public:
    virtual BaseA createA() = 0; // Virtual function, representing method to create A objects
}

class DerB:public BaseB
{
    BaseA createA() {
        DerA* a = new DerA(this); // Definition of createA to make a new A object, specifically one of type DerA (Error1: No instance of constructor "DerA::DerA" matches the argument list)
        return a; // Error2: Cannot return DerA for BaseA function
    }
}
```

So, I have two main problems, one is practical (Error1, as I seem to simply be calling the function wrong, even if I try to typecast `this`), one is philosophical (Error 2, as I don't know how to implement the features I want. If anyone could point out why Error1 is occurring, that would be wonderful!  Error2, however, requires some explanation.

I would like my user (programmer) to interact with all `A` objects the same way.  They will have the same exact public functions, but each will have VERY different implementations of these functions.  Some will be using different data types (and so will require function contracts), but many will have the same data types just with different algorithms that they use on them.  I would like some piece of code to work exactly the same way if one class `A` derivative is used or another is.  However, in my current implementation, it seems that I need to return a `DerA` object instead of a `BaseA` object (at the site of Error2).  This means that I will need to write a segment of main code SPECIFICALLY for a `DerA` object, instead of any arbitrary `A` object.  I would like something like:

```
BaseB b = new DerB(); // Declare which derivative of BaseB I want to use
BaseA a = b->createA(b); // Call the createA function in that derivative, which will automatically make a corresponding A object
```

This way, I can simply choose which type of `B` object I would like in the first line (by my choice of `B` constructor, or tag, or template, or something), and the rest of the code will look the same for any type of object `B` (as each has the same public member functions, even though each object will perform those functions differently).

Would I be better off using templates or some other method instead of inheritance?  (I apologize for being intentionally vague, but I hope my class A/B example should mostly explain what I need).

Thank you for any help.  I apologize for asking two questions in one post and for being long-winded, but I am trying to learn the best way to approach a rather large redesign of some software.

Comment: `class BaseB {}` should be `class BaseB;`

Comment: `virtual BaseA createA()` You shouldn't be returning by value, but by (smart) pointer. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik, fixed!  Also, you are correct, I initially intended to return a reference not the actual object (it's just been a long day :P) Do you know how to deal with the object slicing problem?  You mentioned smart pointers, could I perhaps use a dynamic cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several syntactical issues to get the errors solved:

- Add the `;` after each class definitions.
- The first line should be a forward declaration:  `class BaseB /*{} NO!!*/ ;`
- Add `public:` to make constructor of `DerA` accessible for `DerB`
- `BaseA createA()` should return a value, not a pointner (according to signature):  `return *a;`

There is another potential hidden **slicing issue**, as `createA()` returns a value, an not a pointer.  This means that your returned object (here `*a`),  would be copied but as a real BaseA object.  So only the BaseA part of the object will be copied,  not the derived part. This could lead to some unexpected surprises.

In order to avoid slicing, consider returning a pointer, changing the signature of `createA()` accordingly. The object pointed to would then keep the right type without loosing anything.

If you would later need to copy the object, you could use a static cast if you are absolutely sure of the real type of the object pointed to:

```
   BaseA *pba = pdb->createA();         // get pointer returned 
   DerA da = *static_cast<DerA*>(pba);  // static cast with pointer
```

If you would need to copy pointed BaseA objects without necessarily knwowing for sure their real type, you could implement a virtual clone function in DerA (e.g. [prototype design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern))

Comment: All syntax fixed, and the compiler is happy. I'm sorry for wasting your time on simple syntactical issues.  Do you know how to deal with the object slicing problem (which was what I was trying to reference in Error2)?  I need to get a `DerA` object, but would like to be able to refer to it without slicing off the subclass members. Could "smart pointers" or dynamic casting be used?

Comment: If you define the function as `BaseA *createA()` and return a pointer, you avoid slicing (i.e. the object pointed to has the right type). If you need a `DerA` object and you are sure that the pointer points to such an object, you could then write something like `DerA da = *static_cast<DerA*>(pba);`

Comment: What if I want the ability to capture many different types of objects from derivative classes (`DerA1`, `DerA2`, etc.) which each are subclasses of abstract class `BaseA`?  Can I capture each into some pointer of type `BaseA` by using dynamic casting, or something like that?  They'll each have the same public functions, but each has different private member parameters and functions. I essentially want to be able to do `a->work()` where a is a pointer to either `DerA1`, `DerA2`, etc. without knowing which one until run-time.

Comment: Turns out that passing the object by reference via pointer doesn't cause a slicing problem!  Sorry that I misunderstood.  Thank you for your help, my code is behaving the way that I need it to!